# On click rotate image, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation, fullpage.js

I try to set up image that rotates after links are clicked. having 3 links in total. If second link is clicked, image rotates by 20 degress. If after second link, the third link is clicked, image rotates +20 degrees more. If first link is clicked, image rotates back to default position.
Concept simplified:
link1 = images default position 
link2 = image rotates by 20degrees
link3 = + another 20degrees
If clicked from link3 to link2 -20degrees.

Website uses [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/). Rotating image is meant as navigation dots (see ex. [here](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/navigationV.html#firstPage)).
I dont expect to image to rotate if mouse scroll is used, thats far beyod my reach...

As base I am using [jQuery rotate plugins example 5](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples#Example_5)

```
var value = 0
$("#img").rotate({ 
   bind: 
     { 
        click: function(){
            value +=90;
            $(this).rotate({ animateTo:value})
        }
     } 

});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9ja7/394/) so far... I dont even know how to assign links so that on click image rotates.

Help is highly appreciated. I dont expect to get everything done by someone else, please, at least guide me in direction...

Comment: Should you be binding to the `<a>` tags instead of the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just bind a click event to the `li`. Every time a `li` is clicked check its text.
And based on that rotate your image

Try:

```
var value = 0;
$( "li" ).click(function() {
    var text=$(this).text();
    if(text==="Link1"){value=0;}
    if(text==="Link2"){value+=20;}
    if(text==="Link3"){value-=20;}
    $("#image").rotate({ animateTo:value});

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x9ja7/399/)

Comment: wow, progress!! it should be that if link3 is clicked straight away, image should rotate by two times (meaning 40 degress). any ideas..?

Comment: u guys almost got it, but not quite correct. let me try to explain again:
rotation is more as a steps. it not supposed to rotate if I continuing clicking on link2 for example.  If its clicked on link2, then that is current position. image can continue to rotate only if link1 or link3 is clicked. 

Im doing my best to dig in and do it myself, but without success...

Comment: @bojar I dont quite get what you are trying. Is this demo better?http://jsfiddle.net/x9ja7/405/

Comment: it is, sort of...since link2 acts as I previously described. some how, link3 increses rotation if clicked more than once.

Comment: @bojar You waqnt link1 to put it horizontal, link2 with 20 degrees and link 3 with 40 degree?

Comment: Yes, exactly. it sounds much simpler, when you say that

Comment: Thank you Mr laaposto! there is last question, I would like to ask... 
When object is rotating, I try to get its opacity to 1 (default is .3). Opacity should increase to 1 only when rotating. is it possible?
http://jsfiddle.net/x9ja7/414/ so far...